# In typescript, how to write a function to handle arbitrary dimensional array (e.g.:Array<number>,Array<Array<number>>,...)?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, typescript, typescript2.0

In C++, I can write a template function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
template <typename V>
void f(V& v){
    for(auto& e : v){
        f(e);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

template <>
void f(int& v){
    printf("%d ",v);
}
```

to handle any dimensions of vector in vector(e.g.:vector< int>,vector< vector< int>>,vector< vector< vector< int>>>,...):

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> v1={1,2};
    f(v1);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > v2={{3,4},{5,6,7}};
    f(v2);
    return 0;
};
```

is such a type of function like this:

```
let v1 : Array<number>=[1,2];
f<Array<number>>(v1);

let v2 : Array<Array<number>>=[[3,4],[5,6,7]];
f<Array<Array<number>>>(v2);
```

also possible in typescript? I try something like:

```
f<V>(v : V){
  for(let e in v){
    this.f(e);
  }
}

f<>(v : number){
}
```

but the error says

```
Duplicate function implementation.
```

and I believe I may be in wrong approach

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you are full specializing the function template.
Anyway, generics in typescript are more like generics in Java or C#, not that much similar to templates in C++.
You cannot define full specializations.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one function with the same name, so you need to reconcile both portions into the same function. In this case, a simple check for an array should be sufficient.

```
f(v: any)
{
  if (Array.isArray(v))
    for (let e in v)
      this.f(e);
  else
    doSomething(v);
}
```